# Facebook oauth dialogue login error "An error occurred. Plase try again later."

Tags: java, android, iphone, batch-file, restfb

I keep getting this error "An error occurred. Plase try again later." when I try to login to facebook using oauth dialog in my android and iphone app. I started having this problem only for the last two days. I have no clue as to why this is happening, also no information has been given in the facebook documentation regarding this.

Since it was working fine for such a long time I dont think there is any problem with my code.

FYI : developer.facebook.com is currently under maintenance, could that be a problem..?

Thanks in advance